# checking for empty values in textfield and spinner

Tags: android

```
Button btnSearch = (Button) pnlView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@
    Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        results.clear();
        if (txtPatientID.getText().equals("") && txtFirstName.getText().equals("") 
         && txtLastName.getText().equals("") && txtDOB.getText().equals("") 
                          && cboGender.getSelectedItem().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                       "No criteria added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        new Async().execute();
    }
});
```

I have four text field and a spinner, when the user clicks search button, i need to display a message saying no criteria added. Its working, but i am not sure whether i am following the right approach in checking for empty value in textfield and spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the length instead of comparing with empty value. Because it will fail in one or more cases. you should check like this

```
if(txtPatientID.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
```

`trim()` method will remove one or more spaces in your text

Comment: how if i want to check spinner is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

This seems okay. But you can trim() the getText() results to handle empty space characters.

Comment: Instead of txtPatientID.getText().equals("") use txtPatientID.getText().toString().trim().equals(""). You can also use the solution from Pragani.